# What is a functional structure for multiple files using the same R scripts?

Tags: r, git, version-control

I am trying to get some good practices happening and have recently moved to using git for version control.

One set of scripts I use is for producing measurement uncertainty estimates from laboratory data.  The same scripts are used on different data files and produce a set of files and graphs based on that data.  The core scripts change infrequently.

Should I create a branch for each new data set?  Is this efficient?
Should I use one set of scripts and just manually relocate output files to a separate location after each use?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different aspects here that should be touched on.  I will try provide my opinions/recommendations for each.

1. The core scripts change infrequently.

This sounds to me like you should make an R package of your own. If you some core functions that aren't supposed to change, it would probably be best to package them together.  Ideally, you design the functions so that the code behind each doesn't need to be modified and you just change an argument (or even begin exploring R S3 or S4 classes).

The custom scripting, you could provide a vignette for yourself demonstrating how you approach a data set. If you wanted to save each final script, I would probably store them in the `inst/examples` directory for you to call again if you needed to re-run if you don't want to store them locally.

2. Should I create a branch for each new data set?  Is this efficient?

No, I generally would not ever recommend someone put their data on github.  It is also not 'efficient' to create a new branch for a new data set.  The idea behind creating another branch is to add a new aspect/component to an existing project.  Simply adding a dataset and modifying some scripts is, IMHO, a poor use of a branch.

What you should do with your data depends on the data characteristics.  Is this data large?  Would it benefit from a RDBMS?  You at least want to have it backed up on a local laboratory hard drive.  Secondly, if you are academically minded, once you finish analyzing the data you should look in to an online repository so that others could also analyze the data.  If these datasets are **small**, you could also put them in your package in the `data` directory **if they are not sensitive**.

3. Should I use one set of scripts and just manually relocate output files to a separate location after each use?

No, I would recommend that with your core functions/scripts that you should look in to creating a wrapper for this part and provide an argument to specify the output path.

I hope these comments help you.